# Fancybox3 Youtube videos

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, fancybox

I spent a long time getting familiar with `fancybox2` to display Youtube videos and slide shows now V3 has arrived and not being code savvy I'm wondering if the code I use needs to be changed given that there appears to be only 3 files required: js, css & jquery.

Currently using this script:

```
// fancybox for youtube
$(".youtube").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    maxWidth: 853,
    maxHeight: 480,
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    openSpeed: 250,
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    closeSpeed: 150,
    closeClick: true,
    closeBtn: true,
    iframe: {
        preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
    },
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: { 'background': 'rgba(80, 163, 130, 0.9)' 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You will note I change the colour and the opacity of the overlay to fit in with my web site design and from what googling I've done I understand this may have changed again under version3 but I can't find any documentation on it.
The html calling the script is:

```
<a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U6vutH_9e_0?rel=0&fs=1&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the options you have listed is supported in v3. Actually, you can use v3 without writing a single js line, just create links like this:

```
<a data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U6vutH_9e_0?rel=0&fs=1&autoplay=0">
    YouTube video
</a>
```

and change background color using CSS:

```
.fancybox-bg {
   background: rgba(80, 163, 130, 0.9);
}
```

See demo - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/YVGrgG?editors=1100

Edit: If you want, you can customize color using JavaScript:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  onInit : function( instance ) {
    instance.$refs.bg.css('background', 'rgba(80, 163, 130, 0.9)');
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmyEyg?editors=1010

Comment: That's great so how do you control width & height now and I would like the dark box shadow that used to be default.

Comment: Janis - I tried using CSS by inserting these codes into the <style> and that immediately destroyed the styling on my menu so reverted to jquery again and at least got video this time but still have no style control. Would you be able to show me the correct coding to replace the code above in a $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({ type script.

Comment: Janis - I am trying to reproduce this page using fancybox3 (currently using fancybox2) [link] https://www.whiteshepherdsnz.com/whiteShepherdAssistanceDog.html

Comment: This is how you can change bg color using JS: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmyEyg?editors=1010

Comment: I don't wish to be a pain but I need to know how to reproduce what I have now using the jquery script. Is the button with the cross in the circle still available and how do I get it to where it used to be. Can I get the no frame look with the box shadow as it was. I need to go back to school to understand the documentation and there are so few practical examples with V3 being so new.

Comment: Sure, it is possible - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmyEyg What practical examples are you missing?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Let me take this in and process all my thoughts. I'll be back!

Comment: I started over and created a new test page [link] (https://www.whiteshepherdsnz.com/page1.html) getting closer but overlay or background colour does not come through and the whole frame and contents exceed the 853 x 480.

Comment: You have to include custom css code after including fancybox css or it will be overwritten. Here is sample how to change video size - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#embedding

Comment: I have made further progress, now video size and close button are correct but I cannot get the overlay / background to my colour. Same test page

Comment: I already told you, you have to include jquery.fancybox.min.css file and only then your custom css code (in your case, page1.css)

Comment: OK now I'm confused because the file is there and the link <link  href="fancybox3/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> is in the <head>. Are you saying this line of code needs to be before the page1.css. Placement of this code is governed by the program. I would have to edit  the html on the server to achieve that.

Comment: Ok I did that and we have a result. Is there no way around having to edit the html on the server?

Comment: Either include code in correct order or 1) use CSS !important rule to override 2) set css using js.

Comment: Thanks for your help and education. I shall watch development with interest.

Comment: one last comment - kept original coding without shifting the <link ---> code but added !important to each css line where I wanted my style retained and it worked. Same test page