# FancyBox 3 - Stop duplicates

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I have a primary image you click to open fancybox 3, I also have a thumbnail gallery which is part of the same fancybox group that when you roll over them, they replace the primary image with the one you rolled over - the purpose is to get a "zoom" affect but also offer the fancybox gallery for the rest of the gallery at the same time.
Obviously as the primary item is in the group and  also in the thumbnails I get a duplicate in the fancybox view.

How do I get round this? Here is my attempt, when I try to manipulate what's in the group using Jquery, however, it seems to be ignored when you reopen the fancybox. I wonder if there is a way to unbind and rebind the group (?) but I just can't find it in the documentation.

```
    <!-- Primary Image -->
        <p>
            <a href="/image1.jpg?w=800&h=800&scale=both&bgcolor=white" data-fancybox="fancybox-group" class="fancyboxpreviewlink">
                <img class="fancyboxpreviewimage" src="/image1.jpg?w=800&h=800&scale=both&bgcolor=white" />
            </a>
        </p>

    <!-- Fancybox Gallery -->
            <a href="/image1.jpg?w=800&h=800&scale=both&bgcolor=white" data-fancybox="" class="fancyboxthumb"
               data-thumb="image1.jpg?w=62&h=62&scale=canvas&bgcolor=white">
                <img src="/image1.jpg?w=62&h=62&scale=canvas&bgcolor=white" />
            </a>
            <a href="/image2.jpg?w=800&h=800&scale=both&bgcolor=white" data-fancybox="fancybox-group" class="fancyboxthumb"
               data-thumb="/image2.jpg?w=62&h=62&scale=canvas&bgcolor=white">
                <img src="/image2.jpg?w=62&h=62&scale=canvas&bgcolor=white" /></a>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
//Manipulate group items
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fancyboxthumb').on("mouseenter", function () {
                var $theThumb = $(this);
                var thisHref = ($theThumb.attr("href"));            

                $('.group').unbind('.fancyboxthumb')

                $('.fancyboxthumb').each(function (i, obj)
                {
                    console.log($(obj));
                    console.log("b4: " + $(obj).data("fancybox"));
                    if (!($theThumb.is($(obj))))
                        $(obj).data("fancybox", "fancybox-group");
                    else
                        $theThumb.data("fancybox", "");
                    console.log("after: " + $(obj).data("fancybox"));
                });

                $('.fancyboxpreviewlink').attr("href", thisHref);
                $('.fancyboxpreviewimage').attr("src", thisHref);
            });
            $('.fancyboxthumb').on("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425384/how-do-i-initiate-a-fancybox-3-slideshow-by-clicking-on-a-single-image-or-button

Comment: Thanks Janis, but not quite the same as what I need. I want to see all the thumbs, and a larger preview. Mouse over the thumbs and the preview updates to that thumb....click on that updated large preview and the fancybox starts...but at the index in the group of that preview image. 
Do you know if there is a way in fancybox 3 to load the the group in a fancybox but start at a given index? 
This might be the solution to my problem. I could do it in fancybox 2

Comment: Sure, use `$.fancybox.open( your_group, options, index )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I hope you will get the idea:

```
var index = 0;
var $thumbs  = $('.thumbs').children();
var $primary = $('.primary a');

$primary.on('click', function() {
  // Clone thumbs object
  var $what = $.extend({}, $thumbs);

  // Replace corresponding link inside thumbs with primary  
  $what[ index ] = this;

  // Open fancyBox manually
  $.fancybox.open( $what, {}, index );

  return false;
});

$thumbs.mouseover(function() {
  // Find index
  index = $thumbs.index( this );

  // Update primary link
  $primary.attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
  $primary.find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src') );
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwRzvK?editors=1010

Comment: I think that's the one! Thanks Janis! Your example work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a lot of people may arrive at this question hoping for a solution to actually get rid of duplicates in a fancybox gallery.  It's not exactly what the OP asked, but the question ***title*** certainly sounds like it's about eliminating dupes.

I have a page where there are multiple duplicate images and though I want them all to display and trigger the same gallery, I don't want the dupes in the gallery itself.  Here is a simple method using the `beforeShow()` callback. This uses Fancybox v3 and dynamic binding to "*attach click event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.*" per the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210325170940/https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#initialize-with-javascript):

```
$().fancybox({
    selector : '#my-container a.fancybox',
    beforeShow: function(e) {
        var vals = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < e.group.length; i++) {
            if (vals.indexOf(e.group[i].src) == -1) {
                vals.push(e.group[i].src);
            } else {
                e.group.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```